# Matrix Multiplication of a Pandas DataFrame and Series

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I want to do a matrix multiplcation of a pandas dataframe and a series

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[4,1,3], 'b':[5,2,4]},index=[1,2,3])
ser = pandas.Series([0.6,0.4])
```

df is,

```
 a  b
1  4  5
2  1  2
3  3  4
```

ser is,

```
0    0.6
1    0.4
```

My desired result is a matrix product, like so

ans is,

I can do this by using numpy dot operator and rebuilding my dataFrame

```
c = a.values.dot(b.transpose())
c = pandas.DataFrame(c, index = a.index, columns = ['ans'])
print c


   ans
1  4.4
2  1.4
3  3.4
```

Is there a native method in pandas to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

pandas implicity aligns on the index of a series, use the dot function

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [4,1,3], 'b' : [5,2,4]},index=[1,2,3])

In [4]: s = pd.Series([0.6,0.4],index=['a','b'])

In [5]: df.dot(s)
Out[5]: 
1    4.4
2    1.4
3    3.4
```